# Summing up two arrays or matrices element by element

Tags: vba, excel

I have two variables defined like this:

```
Per_Mnd = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G8").Value
Per_Mnd2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G2:G8").Value
```

Obviously both `Per_Mnd` and `Per_Mnd2` have 7 rows and 1 column. Now I want to sum them up element by element, getting another 7×1 array. How do I do it?

And what is they are defined by matrix

```
Per_Mnd = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:H8").Value
Per_Mnd2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G2:H8").Value
```

How can I quickly sum them up element by element?

thanks!

Comment: So the first element of `Per_Mnd` would be added to the first of `Per_Mnd2`?  The second element added to the second element, etc?

Comment: @Vityata  Poster wants an **array**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply evaluate an INDEX formula to return the array:

```
Sub Test()
Dim oarr As Variant
Dim Per_Mnd As Variant
Dim Per_Mnd2 As Variant
Per_Mnd = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G8").Value
Per_Mnd2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G2:G8").Value

With Application
    oarr = .Transpose(.Evaluate("INDEX({" & Join(.Transpose(Per_Mnd), ",") & "}+{" & Join(.Transpose(Per_Mnd2), ",") & "},)"))
End With


Debug.Print oarr(3, 1)
End Sub
```

---

Note: this only works with single column arrays of the same size.

Comment: Which line specifically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum a matrix, the `VBA` way is `WorksheetFunction.SumProduct`

Take the example below, returning 60 -> `1*10+2*10+3*10`

[image]

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim el1 As Variant
    Dim el2 As Variant
    Dim res As Variant

    el1 = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A3"))
    el2 = Application.Transpose(Range("B1:B3"))
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(el1, el2)

    ReDim res(1 To UBound(el1))
    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = LBound(el1) To UBound(el1)
        res(cnt) = el1(cnt) + el2(cnt)
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

The idea of `Application.Transpose()` is to present the `Range()` as a one dimensional array. Once we do so, we introduce `res(1 to UBound(el1)` where we write the product per element. Or you can even do the `SumArray` as a function, returning the new array:

```
Public Function SumArray(arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant) As Variant

    ReDim res(1 To UBound(arr1))
    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        res(cnt) = arr1(cnt) + arr2(cnt)
    Next cnt

    SumArray = res

End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! but not really what i want... I want (11,12,13)... a 3*1 array

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do without loop? I might have more than 2 arrays... for example, if I have 40 arrays, each 10*1 or 40 matrices, each 10*10, how do I do that?

Comment: And I am not doing any multiplcatin... All I need to do is to add up element in the same position in several arrays...

Comment: with 10x10 arrays you will need to loop but looping memory arrays are quick.

Comment: @TingTing - then instead of `*` you can write `+`, it will work. Concerning the array sum w/o looping - it is a bit problematic, I guess that there would always be some kind of a hidden loop within. Even in `WorksheetFunction.SumProduct` there is a built-in loop, that goes around all the elements of the array. But in general, you can always do a function about it.

Comment: I also got type mismatch for res(cnt) = el1(cnt) * el2(cnt)
... changed * to +

Comment: @TingTing - probably one of the values in the arrays is not a number. It can be text or error, e.g. `Div/0`.

Comment: @TingTing - if you try exactly with my example, would it work?

Comment: Can't believe my eyes... I went for some tea and came back and clicked run without changing any code, and it works...!

Comment: @TingTing - what kind of tea?

Comment: Microsoftea... hahaha

Comment: @Vityata Hi, today i want to change this to a two-dimentional array... i updated the code and the variable is correctly calculated in the Local windows winder. But when writing to Excle file, I again got NA. Could you help to see why?

Comment: Sub try()
Dim Per_Mnd As Variant
Dim Per_Mnd2 As Variant

Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("G2").Value = "111"
Per_Mnd = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("J6:K26"))

Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("G2").Value = "222"
Per_Mnd2 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Res_Lege").Range("J6:K26"))

ReDim res(1 To UBound(Per_Mnd), 1 To 21)

Dim cnt As Long
Dim rnt As Long


For cnt = LBound(Per_Mnd, 1) To UBound(Per_Mnd, 1)
    For rnt = LBound(Per_Mnd, 2) To UBound(Per_Mnd, 2)
        res(cnt, rnt) = Per_Mnd(cnt, rnt) + Per_Mnd2(cnt, rnt)
    Next rnt
Next cnt

Comment: Worksheets("Res_Kontor").Range("J6:K26").Value = res
'Debug.Print oarr(3, 1)

End Sub

Comment: @TingTing - it sounds like a great idea for a new question - you have the code, you know what to expect and you have the input.